# Is there a bibliography of Lebesgue’s publications (with translations)?

Tags: reference-request, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, reference-works

I’m reading in the history of measure and integration and can’t find a complete list of Lebesgue’s publications, which I understand comprise his PhD thesis, some 50 papers, and two monographs. (Wikipedia in English does not give such a list.)

1. Does such a complete bibliography exist? If so, where?
2. Have there been any complete English translations of these works? If so, where?
3. Is there a volume (in French even) of the collected papers?

Comment: There is [this](https://data.bnf.fr/fr/11911865/henri_lebesgue/), and you can find several of his works on [Gallica](https://gallica.bnf.fr/) (website of the french national library). The [Wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri-L%C3%A9on_Lebesgue) in french has also a list, with several links to [NumDam](http://www.numdam.org/).

Comment: There seems to be also an edition of his works, *"Oeuvres scientifiques"*, in 5 volumes, published in 1972, but I don't have much information on this.